# Reading a pdf with wrapped text in R

Tags: r, pdf, dplyr, reformatting

I am having an issue bringing a pdf into R.

It's working great except that in the PDF there some company names that are too long and thus split into 2 lines (wrapped text), so when I use pdftools R is still parsing the info in the wrong way for those lines. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Here is how the document looks like - the issues are with record 3 and record 4.
[image]

here is my code:

```
library(pdftools)
dfpdf <- pdf_text('./data/record.pdf') %>%
stringr::str_split('\n', simplify = T) %>%
matrix(ncol = 1)

tab_start <- stringr::str_which(dfpdf, ' Uppdrag att')
tab_end <- stringr::str_which(dfpdf, '                      Visar uppdrag')
tab <- dfpdf[(tab_start+1):(tab_end-1), 1] %>%
  str_replace_all('\\s{2,}', '\t')
text_conn <- textConnection(tab)
df <- read.csv(text_conn, sep = '\t', skip = 1)
```

This is what I get:
[image]

Record 3 and record 4 are taking up an extra line with the wrapped text.

you can get a similar pdf sample from [enter link description here](http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/gamecenter/56901/DEN_Gamebook.pdf), page 9.
the lines look like:

I appreciate any suggestions (including better ways to read a pdf and ways to simplify my code).

Thank you!

Comment: Often data from .pdf  have to be "cleaned" after reading them, this is IMO perfectly normal. You could exploit the fact that the date is missing in those extra rows, and that they always are to be merged with the preceding row. Not the most satisfying job, though, good luck!